# How to get variable name of reference arguments in Swift code?

Tags: swift

```
var bankAccountBalance = 3000000.00
var macbookpro = 191000.00
var iphone6sPlus = 59000.00
var newSweetHome = 3500000.00
var amountRequired = 00.00

func purchaseItem1(currentBalance : Double, itemPrice : Double) ->Double {
    if(itemPrice<=currentBalance)
    {
        print("Purchased item for :\(itemPrice)")
        print("Your current outstanding Account balance is \(currentBalance)")

        return currentBalance-itemPrice   
    }
    else {
        amountRequired = itemPrice - currentBalance

        print("You dont have enough account balance to purchase this item :( ")
        print("You need \(amountRequired)Rs in your bank")
        return amountRequired
    }
}

purchaseItem1(currentBalance: bankAccountBalance, itemPrice: macbookpro)
purchaseItem1(currentBalance: bankAccountBalance, itemPrice: iphone6sPlus)
purchaseItem1(currentBalance: bankAccountBalance, itemPrice: newSweetHome)
```

Comment: i want to get name of items which is variable name and is passed in function as an arguments

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: sir @Alexander i am asking that getting the name of variable from arguments passed in function purchaseItem1(currentBalance : Double, itemPrice : Double). i want the name of passed arguments in function to print.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Have you considered using a dictionary instead, e.g.

`let items = ["MacBook Pro": 191000.0, "iPhone 6S Plus": 59000.0"]`

Or you should probably really be encoding this information in some sort of data structure, e.g.

```
struct Item {
    var name: String
    var price: Double
}

let items = [
    Item(name: "MacBook Pro", price: 191000), 
    Item(name: "iPhone 6S Plus", price: 59000)
]
```

Comment: thankyou so much sir. i am new to swift and just started learning swift.